# get the current tab in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs inside of the jQuery UI dialog window.

I've come across an instance, where I need to find the id of the current tab when clicking on one of the dialog buttons.  Looking at the HTML generated by jQuery UI tabs and dialog, I can't really find a way of doing this. The `<ul>` elements that hold the tab, are about 3 `<div>`'s away from the group of dialog buttons.

I tried:

```
$("#DialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
        text: "Save",
        click: function () {
        var currentTabId = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
        alert(currentTabId);
```

But I just get an 'undefined' alert back.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to manual http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ getter of active JqueryUI tab is

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

*Replace `".selector"` by your one.

Then `active.attr( 'id' )` will return exactly what you need.

Comment: +1 for the first part.  But `active.attr( 'id' )` will not work, because `active` contains merely a number.  So you cannot get the id using it.

Comment: Also depending on which jQuery version you're using you may need to replace 'active' with 'selected'.

Comment: That is not the answer,he needs id of selected tab while this answer gives index of active tab.@Michael answer is correct.

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me (jQuery 1.9, jQueryUI 1.10).  I have not tested this for earlier versions of jQueryUI, but if you have jQueryUI 1.8 or earlier, instead of 'active' try using 'select'.

```
// GET INDEX OF ACTIVE TAB
// make sure to replace #tabs with the actual selector
// that you used to create the tabs
var activeTabIdx = $('#tabs').tabs('option','active');

// ID OF ACTIVE TAB
// make sure to change #tabs to your selector for tabs
var selector = '#tabs > ul > li';
var activeTabID = $(selector).eq(activeTabIdx).attr('id');

// ID OF ACTIVE TAB CONTENT
// make sure to change #tabs to your selector for tabs
var selector = '#tabs [id=ui-tabs-' + (activeTabIdx + 1) + ']';
var activeTabContentID = $(selector).attr('id');
```

Comment: its giving erro ron 'option' .......Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
 

throw new Error( msg );

Comment: The error is correct.  If you haven't initialized the tabs yet you will get this error when trying to get the option.  The code in this answer is correct and works on initialized tabs (depending on version; I had luck with the `aria-controls` rather than `id`; `.ui-tabs-active` appears viable as well, although w/o documentation it may change in future versions).  See the other answers for reference.

Comment: ID of active tab content didn't work for me - instead I was able to use `$(selector).eq(activeTabIdx).find("a").attr("href")` (using the first value for `selector`)

Comment: The id of the active tab content panel is set by the user... It is in no way based on the active tab index.  The anchor defined in the <li> of the tag will have an id generated by JQuery that looks like ui-tabs-88, but it also is not related to the index of the tab....  It's just a unique id generated by JQuery and I think it's value is based on how many widgets have already been created on your page.

Answer (score 15):

Use following in case of jQuery 1.9+,

```
var currentTabId = $('div[id="mytabs"] ul .ui-tabs-active').attr("id");
```

Comment: This looks like the actual answer.

Comment: Correct but why on earth was the API removed??  It is not like fetching the active tab is an uncommon operation.

Answer (score 10):

For **JQuery UI 1.11+** this worked for me:

```
$("ul>.ui-tabs-active").attr('aria-controls');
```

Answer (score 5):

⚡ worked for me this way ⚡

```
var currentTab=$("ul> .ui-tabs-active").attr('aria-controls');
console.log(currentTab);
```

Comment: the selector , ".ul>.ui-tabs-active " did not work for me , ul is not class and it needed the space between ,

Comment: The class-part is correct, thanks. However, note that if you add the space, it might not work for nested tabs.

Answer (score 5):

here is the correct one and the simplest:

```
var active = $(".tab-pane.active").attr("id");
console.log(active);
```

You should add active selector next to tab-pane. This will return the current active tab ID.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

```
var current_tab = $("#tabs .ui-state-active a").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//for getting selected tabs

var tabs = $("#tabs").children().find(".current").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Asume that ui tabs container's id is tab-container. Working snippet is

```
$('#tab-container').find('>div:nth-of-type(' + ($('#tab-container').tabs("option", "active") + 1) + ')');
```

Tested with jQuery UI v1.11.2, jQuery v1.11.3 and Chrome 45.

Answer (score 0):

This also works, using JQuery 3.1.1 and Jquery UI 1.12.1, when you need to select your active tab in javascript (by "select" I mean in a JQuery selector, not "select" in the sense of making the tab active, since of course the tab is already active).

To get a reference to the currently selected tab, first get a reference to the active link (substitute the id of your tabs container "myTabs"):

```
var $link = $('div[id=myTabs] ul .ui-tabs-active');
```

$link has the id the tab in the attribute "aria-controls":

```
var $tab = $('#' + $link.attr('aria-controls'));
```

$tab is a reference to the tab body.  For example, you could call

```
$tab.html('[html here]')
```

to fill or replace the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is relevant for JQuery UI 1.12 and probably a few versions before.)

It depends what you mean by tab... There is the thing that you click to select a tab and the panel that is displayed because of the click. The thing you click  is a list item `<li>` that contains an anchor `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute that points to the panel id (it's prepended with a '#'). The panel id and href values are set by you (not JQuery). The list item has no id by default, but the anchor element does... it is generated by JQuery and will be something like 'ui-id-88'. To get either the tab id, anchor id or the panel id, you can use the following:

```
// if you have nested tabs this might not work... in such case, give 
// your parent tab and panel a unique class and use it in selector
var $tabs = $("#tabs");
var tabIndex = $tabs.tabs("option", "active");
var $tab = $tabs.find("li[role=tab]").eq(tabIndex);
var tabId = $tab.attr("id"); // undefined unless set by user
var anchorId = $tab.attr("aria-labelledby"); // or $tabs.find("ul li a.ui-tabs-anchor").eq(tabIndex).attr("id");
var panelId = $tab.attr("aria-controls"); //or $tabs.find(".ui-tabs-panel").eq(tabIndex).attr("id");
// note: panelId will also be in href of anchor with prepended # sign
alert("tabId=" + tabId + ", anchorId=" + anchorId + ", panelId=" + panelId);
```