# jQuery if element is on current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am using [tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to break up a long form that has many entry fields.

My form has 4 tabs and a preview of the users selection below the tabs form.

In the preview below the tabs, I have placed icons that allow the user to scroll back up to the input element on the tab that has the input element.

This works great when the user is viewing the correct tab that they want to scroll up to. For example, if the input element is on tab 1 and the user is viewing tab 1, the user can scroll back up to that element on tab 1.

However, if the input element is on tab 1 and the user is viewing tab 2, the scroll up does not work. I am assuming that this is because the element is not visible on the tab/form (but the element does indeed exist).

So I made a conditional if/else statement to test if the element is reachable, but the condition always returns true. I cannot work out what the condition should be to check if the element is reachable on the tab or not.

I have tried different conditions, but all return true.

I am hoping that someone has a workable suggestion.

Here is my code:

```
function scrollUpSingleDocumentDetails(id){
    //if(!($("#"+id).length)){
    if($("#"+id).css('visibility') === 'hidden'){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top-50},'slow');
    } else {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#id_details_headline").offset().top-50},'slow');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the current tab as per [get the current tab in jQuery UI tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302593/get-the-current-tab-in-jquery-ui-tabs)

Use the id of the tab to get the element, lets say it was "currenttab", and lets say your input's id in "inputId":

```
var tab=document.getElementById('currentTab');
var input = document.getElementById('inputId'); 

if (tab.contains(input)) 
{ 
  alert("input is visible")
}
```